# How can I restore data that I soft deleted with gorm deletedAt

Tags: go, go-gorm

Currently using gorm and I soft deleted one data
I know how to get data that its soft deleted
But I need to restore it so if anyone know how to do it please let me know

Answer (score 5):

https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Update-single-column

You can update the `deleted_at` column to `NULL`, e.g.

```golang
db.Model(&User{}).Where("id", 1).Update("deleted_at", nil)
```

Example:

```golang
type User struct {
    gorm.Model
    gorm.DeletedAt
    Name string
}

db.AutoMigrate(&User{})
db.Create(&User{Name: "John Doe"})

u := new(User)
fmt.Println(db.First(u, 1).Error) // nil
db.Delete(u, 1)
fmt.Println(db.First(u, 1).Error) // record not found
db.Model(u).Update("deleted_at", nil)
fmt.Println(db.First(u, 1).Error) // nil
```

Answer (score 4):

With the latest GORM version, need to unscoped it to activate the soft deleted records.

```
db.Unscoped().Model(&model{}).Where("id", id).Update("deleted_at", nil)
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if an undelete, mentioned in [issue 4388](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4388) would help:

```golang
model.DeletedAt = gorm.DeletedAt{}
if err := o.DbPointer.Table(table).Save(&model).Error; err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Although [re-inserting soft-deleted relation in a custom join table](https://github.com/go-gorm/gorm/issues/4646) does not seem obvious (or working).